# LINQ Query with method syntax

Tags: c#, performance, linq

My requirement is to make boolean value (IsPC=true) only if I found any value with IsCurrent = true from the list and second condition is to filter the list with G or W codes and third condition is to check the PCBNumber length ==15 with only one from the list.

How short can i able to reduce the below query using LINQ method syntax
below is my query

```
     var CurrentQ= p.List.Where(x => x.IsConCurrent== true);
            if (CurrentQ.Count() > 0)
            {
                var NCurrentQwithWorQ = p.List.Where(x => x.Codes == Codes.W|| x.Codes== Codes.Q).Count();
                if (NCurrentQwithWorQ  != null)
                {
                    var PCBNumber = p.List.Where(x => x.PCBNumber .Length == 15).Count();
                    if (PCBNumber == 1)
                    {
                        isPC = true;
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Why the `NCurrentQwithWorQ != null` check? `NCurrentQwithWorQ` will never be `null`.

Comment: As per the code in given in OP, all 3 conditions doesn't quite meet for the same element in p.List. Is that intentional ?

Comment: Also, the `isPC` is undefined if  `NCurrentQwithWorQ == 0` or `PCBNumber != 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use all conditions in same query like below,

```
var PCBNumber= p.List.Where(x => x.IsConCurrent== true && (x.Codes == Codes.W|| x.Codes== Codes.Q) && x.PCBNumber.Length == 15);
if (PCBNumber !=null && PCBNumber.Count() == 1)
{
   isPC = true;
}
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to the original. Your version requires the same element to meet all of the conditions.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes during copy paste it got missed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not trying to debug what you wrote, but isn't this really what you're looking for--that is, daisy-chaining your Where conditions?

`var isPC = p.List.Where(x => x.IsConCurrent == true).Where(x => x.Codes == Codes.W || x.Codes == Codes.Q).Where(x => x.PCBNumber.Length == 15).Count() == 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions suggested above are correct.

```
p.List.Where(x => x.IsConCurrent== true && (x.Codes == Codes.W|| x.Codes== Codes.Q) && x.PCBNumber.Length == 15);
p.List.Where(x => x.IsConCurrent == true).Where(x => x.Codes == Codes.W || x.Codes == Codes.Q).Where(x => x.PCBNumber.Length == 15).Count()
```

Actually they are performed in the same way. The Where function does not force immediate iteration through the data source. Only when you execute the Count function, LINQ will process row by row and execute criterion by criterion to find out which values should be calculated.

I can only suggest you add the Take(2) operator after the where clause. In this case LINQ will stop after finding the first two rows that matches provided criterion and other rows will not be processed.

```
p.List.Where(x => x.IsConCurrent == true)
   .Where(x => x.Codes == Codes.W || x.Codes == Codes.Q)
   .Where(x => x.PCBNumber.Length == 15)
   .Take(2).Count()
```